# how to send binary file to server with Cypress using request

Tags: cypress

I need before the test to upload directly from Cypress API to server an excel-table (without any *input[type="file"]*, just plain file submission) and then it will be requested back with some other data and used by the test.

So i tried in different ways to make Cypress to use the file by *fixture*, *readfile* with different data-encodings, but neigther was working.

As soon as file is received successfully some rest of the code must run.

```
  before(() => {

  cy.fixture("data/catalog.xlsx", "binary")
    .then(content => {

      cy.wrap(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(content, "utf8"))
        .then(blob => {

          const file = new File([blob], "catalog-table", {type: "utf8"});

          cy.request("POST", "http://localhost:28080/app/admin/api/catalog/import/xlsx", file)
            .then(res => {debugger; expect(res.ok).to.be.true})
            .as("fileSend");

          cy.wait("@fileSend")
            .then(() => {some other code to be executed});
        })
    })
})
```

also tried to add few more headers lines

```
          cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:28080/app/admin/api/catalog/import/xlsx",
            headers: {
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
            },
            cache: 'no-cache',
            body: file
          })
```

Comment: can you show the model of the API controller which you're trying to hit. btw what is the error on doing this ?

Comment: @Prany, thanks for you help, but the api was correct for sure, but Cypress wasnt working with *new FormData* at all,  i found some reported bugs about it

Comment: but if you add `form:true` then it will consider the input as form data ?

Comment: @Prany where do you mean to place form:true and what is it for? because in my case there is no any input field to get files placed before the tests, it stores in localy and directly sends the file to server api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that neither **cy.request** nor **Cypress.$.ajax** werent working at all with files.

My problem was hidden in two issues:

1. the way of handling the file before submission;
2. faulty native cypress request method

Here are some details to take into account:

- Take a file to dispatch it from the local:

```
before(() => { //run before the tests
  cy.fixture(filePath, "binary")
```

- Prepare it as a binary one:

```
    .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
    .then(blob => {
      const file = new File([blob], fileName);
```

- Make it a part of data submitting:

```
      let data = new FormData();

      //settings for host server
      data.append("catalogName", fileName);
      data.append("xlsxFile", file);
```

- Request-workaround in spite of **cy.request** nor **Cypress.$.ajax**:

```
      cy.form_request(url, data)
        .then(response => { some other code})
    })
})
```

Because
**Cypress.$.ajax** was illegaly invoked but in the web its difficult to find out the source of problem.
**cypress** crashed on **formData** preparation;
I found that out from *Network* section in Devtool there was no any XHR request because it failed from the start.

I found third way by [native XHR workaround](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1647#issuecomment-407821503)
and there is the custom request ***cy.form_reques*** placed in commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("form_request", (url, formData) => {
  return cy
    .server()
    .route("POST", url)
    .as("formRequest")
    .window()
    .then(win => {
      var xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url);
      xhr.send(formData);
    })
    .wait("@formRequest");
});
```

Comment: Good one.
however got one issue here.
.wait("@formRequest") keep waiting with no response.
i tried to add increase the timeout to 60 sec. but it's still waiting. 
i just removed the assertion till I find a solution

Comment: So this worked with me:
I removed  .wait("@formRequest") 
and added this after xhr.send(formData);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
        }
    }